# How to remove the padding around an icon in desktop in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: desktop, ubuntu-20.04

I want to remove the padding around an icon in Ubuntu Desktop. How can I do that?
[image]

Comment: Are you using a theme?

Comment: @ChanganAuto yes I'm

Comment: So that's the likely reason, a quirk of the specific theme you're using. It isn't how icons are normally shown with the standard theme or all the few others I've tested.